# JavaScript Resource Error

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I'm encountering an error in Chrome's console where it returns:

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
```

I've read other posts related to this and how it may be the path that I specified is where the error is occurring. But since I don't have much experience with this, I can't seem to find where the error is. The script.js file may look a bit weird since it's compiled from a TypeScript file. Another error that I'm encountering is that when I load the HTML page and then refresh it, the error is a bit different. The different error is:

> GET
>   http://localhost:63342/WeatherWizard/src/html/api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?lat=49.1438509&lon=-123.11269889999998
>   404 (Not Found) send @ bundle.js:9666 ajax @ bundle.js:9273
>   jQuery.(anonymous function) @ bundle.js:9422 getJSON @ bundle.js:9403
>   (anonymous) @ bundle.js:32 locationSuccess @ bundle.js:31

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>WeatherWizard</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale = 1">
    <link   rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-PsH8R72JQ3SOdhVi3uxftmaW6Vc51MKb0q5P2rRUpPvrszuE4W1povHYgTpBfshb" crossorigin="anonymous">        <!-- Makes me host Bootstrap -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/4c5e04f914.js"></script>
    <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.0.0/moment.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../js/bundle.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="jumbotron text-center">
        <h1 id="filler">Weather Wizard</h1>
        <p>Finding your local weather!</p>
        <!-- Your current location is: -->
        <p id="currentCity">hello where is this</p>
    </div>

    <nav class="navbar">
        <div class="d-flex justify-content-end">    <!-- TODO: don't know if it should be justify-content-end or justify-content-start // both give the same result -->
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <div class="navbear-header">
                    <a class="navbar-brand" href="">WeatherWizard27</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <form class="form-inline">
            <div class="form-group">
                <input class="form-control" type="text"  placeholder="Location">
                <div class="input-group-btn">
                    <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm 0" type="submit">
                        <i class="fa fa-search" aria-hidden="true"> Search</i>      <!-- TODO: change to boostrap's font-->
                    </button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
    </nav>

    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col">
                <h2>Monday</h2>
            </div>
            <div class="col">
                <h2>Tuesday</h2>
            </div>
            <div class="col">
                <h2>Wednesday</h2>
            </div>
            <div class="col">
                <h2>Thursday</h2>
            </div>
            <div class="col">
                <h2>Friday</h2>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

**script.js**

```
"use strict";
Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", { value: true });
const WeatherData_1 = require("./WeatherData");
const $ = require("jquery");
$(document).ready(function () {
var deg = 'c';
var weatherDiv = $('#weather');
var location = $('p.location');
getLocation();
function getLocation() {
    document.getElementById("filler").innerHTML = "is this showing up?";
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(locationSuccess, locationError);
    }
    else {
        showError("Your browser does not support Geolocation!");
    }
}
function locationSuccess(position) {
    var lat = position.coords.latitude;
    var lon = position.coords.longitude;
    try {
        return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
            $.getJSON("api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?lat=" + lat + "&lon=" + lon, function (weatherResponse) {
                resolve(weatherResponse);
            });
        }).then(function (weatherResponse) {
            var weatherData = new WeatherData_1.WeatherData();
            var assignedWeatherData = setWeatherDataHelper(weatherData, weatherResponse);
            displayCurrentCity(assignedWeatherData);
        });
    }
    catch (err) {
        showError("We can't find information about your city!");
    }
}
;
function setWeatherDataHelper(weatherData, weatherResponse) {
    var date = new Date();
    console.log("created a new Date object");
    weatherData.date = formatTimeIntoAMPM(date);
    weatherData.city = weatherResponse.city.name;
    weatherData.country = weatherResponse.country;
    weatherData.temperature = weatherResponse.list.main.temp;
    weatherData.minTemperature = weatherResponse.list.main.temp_min;
    weatherData.maxTemperature = weatherResponse.list.main.temp_max;
    weatherData.weather = weatherResponse.list.weather.id;
    weatherData.weatherIcon = weatherResponse.list.weather.icon;
    return weatherData;
}
function locationError(error) {
    switch (error.code) {
        case error.TIMEOUT:
            showError("A timeout occurred! Please try again!");
            break;
        case error.POSITION_UNAVAILABLE:
            showError('We can\'t detect your location. Sorry!');
            break;
        case error.PERMISSION_DENIED:
            showError('Please allow geolocation access for this to work.');
            break;
        case error.UNKNOWN_ERROR:
            showError('An unknown error occured!');
            break;
    }
}
;
function showError(msg) {
    weatherDiv.addClass('error').html(msg);
}
;
function formatTimeIntoAMPM(date) {
    console.log("got into format time method");
    var minutes = date.getMinutes.toString().length === 1 ? '0' + date.getMinutes() : date.getMinutes();
    var hours = date.getHours().toString().length == 1 ? '0' + date.getHours() : date.getHours();
    var ampm = date.getHours() >= 12 ? 'pm' : 'am';
    var months = ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec'];
    var combinedDate = date.getDay() + ' ' + months[date.getMonth()] + ' ' + date.getDate() + ' ' + hours + minutes + ampm;
    return combinedDate;
}
;
function displayWeatherData(assignedWeatherData) {
}
;
function displayCurrentCity(assignedWeatherData) {
    console.log("got into displayCurrentCity method");
    var element = document.getElementById("currentCity");
    element.innerHTML = assignedWeatherData.city + ", " + assignedWeatherData.country;
}
});
//# sourceMappingURL=script.js.map
```

Comment: what is `"//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.0.0/moment.min.js`?

Comment: It was something I was supposed to be using that helped with date and time. I was following this tutorial: https://tutorialzine.com/2013/05/weather-web-app-geolocation-revisited

Comment: copy the url into your browsers url address bar and see if there is anything there

Comment: Ah, there isn't anything there and I'm guessing that's where the 404 error was from. Seems like I'm still getting the same error message even when that line is removed.

Comment: @JonathanWang I know we are already used `moment.js` I meant put `https` before the address in your HTML head like `https://cdnjs.cloudflare..` and also in your code you are getting the resource with no true address lik `api.openweathermap.org` ...

Comment: By true address, do you mean what @JoshKisb suggested in the answers below?

Comment: This is better to download all your related `js` files to your solution and use relative address like `yourFolderAddress/yourFile.js`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should probably use an absolute url for external resources

change

```
$.getJSON("api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?lat=" + lat + "&lon=" + lon, function (weatherResponse) {
       resolve(weatherResponse);
});
```

to

```
$.getJSON("https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?lat=" + lat + "&lon=" + lon, function (weatherResponse) {
       resolve(weatherResponse);
});
```

or simply

```
$.getJSON("//api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?lat=" + lat + "&lon=" + lon, function (weatherResponse) {
       resolve(weatherResponse);
});
```

Comment: Thanks! I'll make sure to change it to that. Curious as to why absolute URL's are better or preferred?

Comment: because a relative url is appended to your current url. for example `api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?lat=49.1438509&lon=-123.11269889999998` is appended to your current url `http://localhost:63342/WeatherWizard/src/html/` to produce incorrect url `http://localhost:63342/WeatherWizard/src/html/api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?lat=49.1438509&lon=-123.11269889999998`

Comment: let me use shorter example. if you call `google.com` when you are on `http://localhost/myapp/` the resulting url will be `http://localhost/myapp/google.com`

Comment: So just to make sure I got this right, NOT including http:// will append the url to localhost and result in a 404. But, if I do include http:// , it won't append to the end of localhost (correct way)

Answer (score 0):

This error occurs because you need to use 'http://' at the start of your API URL. Otherwise, it will be treated as a local address

Comment: Thank you! I've made that change!